# Select rows in SQL with most dense (fewest NULL) column data

Tags: sql

I have multiple duplicate IDs, which need to be reduced to a single value.  Ordinarily I would use an aggregation method to combine column values (as a sum, mean, etc).  Here, I am interested in just keeping the row with the greatest number of non-null values across all the columns:

given this table:

```
id   col1   col2   col3
1    a      ''     ''
1    a      b      ''
2    x      y      ''
1    a      b      c
2    s      ''     ''
```

How I could select:

```
id   col1   col2   col3
2    x      y      ''
1    a      b      c
```

Comment: Which rdbms are you using and does this table contain only these 4 columns?

Comment: Could any combination of columns be null, or will it only be [null,null,null],[a,null,null], or [a,b,null].  also, do you really mean NULL, your example has values of '' in those columns

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this query:

```
select id, 
  max(
    (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +   
    (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
    (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
  ) maxnotnulls
from tablename
group by id
```

you can get for each id the maximum number of not null columns for each id. 
So you can join the table with the above query like this:

```
select t.* from tablename t
inner join (
  select id, 
    max(
      (case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +   
      (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
      (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
    ) maxnotnulls
  from tablename
  group by id
) g 
on 
  g.id = t.id
  and 
  (case when t.col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +   
  (case when t.col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
  (case when t.col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) = g.maxnotnulls
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the empty string is really `NULL`, the simplest method in standard SQL is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by ((case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                                          (case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
                                          (case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc
                                         )
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Of course, this readily adapts to comparisons to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an suqery for the max sum of not null and join 
eg limiting to the top 2

```
select m.* from  
my_table m
INNER JOIN (
  select id
   , if (col1 is null, 0, 1)  + 
     if (col2 is null, 0,  1)  + 
     if (col3 is null, 0, 1)   result 

  from my_table 
  order by  result desc 
  limit 2
) t on t.id = m.id
```

Comment: This answer is a bit ridiculous.  It may work for the OPs particular data, but it would not do the expected thing if there were more than two ids or if the ids were tied for the number of non-NULL columns.